# how do I loop through this database and get the child values?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this database, which looks like this
[image]

so the first keys are user uid taken from auth, and then the username he/she provided and what did they score for each match are taken also..

I just wanted to get each user total points - for example **Ray** total points is **45** and **Wood** total points is **44** but after looking through for the docs all I was able to do was just for one user, I have to write each user name and the specific match for each line to get the value.. now think of how it will be if they are dozens of users? hmm a lot of lines..

here is the [**JSON**](https://jsonblob.com/f69b739d-4ded-11e7-ae4c-c7e708869ca1)

the javascript code

```
var query = firebase.database().ref();
 query.once("value")
 .then(function(snapshot) {
 snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

  var key = childSnapshot.key;      
  var Data1 = childSnapshot.child("Ray/Match1/Points").val();
  var Data2 = childSnapshot.child("Ray/Match2/Points").val();
  console.log(Data1 + Data2);
  });
 })
```

which will let me display, Ray total points, but not for Wood obviously I have to repeat it and write it..

So how do i solve this?

Comment: this is a type of question where firebase cloud functions outshines every other frontend implementation.

Answer (score 6):

I took a look at your problem and I think I have your solution, or at the very least a PATHWAY to your solution. Ok, first I'll explain the basic issue, then I'll attempt to provide you with some generic-ish code (I'll attempt to use some of the variables you used). And away we go!

Basically what I see is 2 steps...

STEP 1 - You need to use a "constructor function" that will create new user objects with their own name (and/or user ID) and their own set of properties.

With that line of thinking, you can have the constructor function include properties such as "user name", "match points 1", "match points 2" and then a function that console logs the summary of each name and their total points from match points 1 and 2.

STEP 2 - You need to put the constructor function inside of a loop that will go through the database looking for the specific properties you need to fill in the properties needed by the constructor function to spit out the info you're looking for.

So... and let's take a deep breath because that was a lot of words... let's try to code that. I'll use generic properties in a way that I think will make it easy for you to insert your own property/variable names.

```
var user = function(name, match1, match2){
    this.name = name;
    this.match1 = match1;
    this.match2 = match2;
    this.pointTotal = function(match1, match2) {
        console.log(match1 + match2);};
    this.summary = function(){
            console.log(name + " has a total of " + pointTotal + " 
points.");};
}
```

the "This" part of the code allows ANY user name to be used and not just specific ones.

Ok, so the code above takes care of the constructor function part of the issue. Now it doesn't matter how many users you need to create with unique names.

The next step is to create some kind of loop function that will go through the database and fill in the properties needed to create each user so that you can get the total points from EVERY user and not just one.

Again, I will use generic-ish property/variable names...

```
var key = childSnapshot.key;

while(i = 0; i < key.length + 1; i++) {

    var user = function(name, match1, match2){
        this.name = name;
        this.match1 = match1;
        this.match2 = match2;
        this.pointTotal = function(match1, match2) {
            console.log(match1 + match2);};
        this.summary = function(){
            console.log(name + " has a total of " + pointTotal + " points.");};
    }
}
```

That is a whole lot of words and the code is a hybrid of generic property names/variables and of property names/variables used by you, but I'm certain that I am on the correct pathway.

I have a lot of confidence that if you used the code and EXPLANATION that I provided, that if you plug in your own variables you will get the solution that you need.

In closing I just want to say that I REALLY hope that helps and if it doesn't I'd like to help solve the problem one way or another because I need the practice. I work a job with weird hours and so if I don't answer right away I am likely at my job :(

Good luck and I hope I helped!

Comment: Looks like Mohammed beat me to the punch and with a much simpler solution! I will reverse engineer his answer so that I can understand it for myself. Hey... BRAVO Mohamed!  :)

Comment: thanks for taking your time to write this, can you show me an example of json? do you mean like this https://jsonblob.com/f22313a3-4e29-11e7-ae4c-096d61fc72e0

Comment: Hey skyline! Unfortunately, I'm embarrassed to say that I don't know the first thing about json yet. I just know html, css and javascript, but I'm getting pretty comfortable with javascript and recognized the javascript in your problem and saw how it could have been solved.

Answer (score 5):

simply add **total** node to your db

```
|_Id
   |_ $userId:
   |       |_ Ray
   |       |    |_ Match1:24
   |       |    |_ Match2:21
   |       |_ total:45
```

and then get user`s total

```
var query = firebase.database().ref();
 query.once("value")
 .then(function(snapshot) {
 snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  var total = childSnapshot.child("total").val();
  console.log(total);
  });
 })
```

you can add the total node using [cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)

Comment: Great answer Mohamed. I'd make a change though and store the total score separate from the match results, so that you can retrieve just the total scores for all users. So `/TotalScores/$uid/45`

Comment: Is that the only way we can do it? via cloud function? I just want to build a simple static site so there must be another way or ?

Comment: There are always several ways to solve your problems.
 But I think its more convenient to implement your logic in the backend(a simple node function in your case).
Alternatively you can add points to the total each time you save a match in your database.

Comment: seems a lot of work to go through node and those stuff for just displaying total points.. I may look at PHP/MySql for now if there is no other way

Comment: As your app grow bigger, It would be more efficient, and secure to keep your logic backend.
In the end it`s your call.

Comment: @skyline33 it's arguable the best approach. Plus the logic lies in the server, not in the front end. So you can make logic changes without having to update your front end..

Answer (score 3):

Check out this implementation. No need for cloud function.

```
 firebase().database().ref().on('value', function(snapshot) {
 snapshot.forEach((user)=>{

  user.forEach((matches)=> {
     var total = 0;
     matches.forEach((match)=> {       
         total += match.val().Points;          
     }); 
     console.log(total);                         
   });    

  });
 })
```

Comment: While this is correct, it's not optimal because you need to loop through on front end. Mohamed's is better because it hides the logic from the app (more secure). Plus, firebase is a nosql database. So, it'll be better to approach it from nosql point of view for optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

> If the key is the user's Id, why add yet another nested object with the user's name? Do you expect one user to have multiple usernames? That sounds weird and adds on complexity, as you have probably noticed. If you need to keep the user name somewhere in Firebase, it is recommended that you dedicate a user details section somewhere directly under the user Id key. Here is a JavaScript representation of the Firebase object structure:

```
{
  a1230scfkls1240: {
    userinfo: {
      username: 'Joe'
    },
    matches: {
      asflk12405: {
        points: 123
      },
      isdf534853: {
        points: 345
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Now, getting to the total points seems a bit more straightforward, does it not?

To help you without modifying your current database structure, all you need is to loop through all the userId+username+matches permutation in your database. Here is an example code to achieve just that, you do not need any special Firebase feature, just good old JavaScript for-of loop:

```
const query = firebase.database().ref();

query.once('value')
.then(snapshot => {
  const points = {}
  const users = snapshot.val()

  for (const userId of Object.keys(users)) {
    const userprofile = users[userId]

    for (const username of Object.keys(userprofile)) {
      const user = userprofile[username]

      for (const matchId of Object.keys(user)) {
        const match = user[matchId]
        // Store the points per user, per profile, or per both, depending on your needs
        points[username] = points[username] === undefined
          ? points[username] = match.points
          : points[username] += match.points
      }
    }
  }
})
```